# In MSDN, What does TBD stand for?

Tags: windows, winapi, 64-bit, marshalling, msdn

Here is a list of [RPC Data Marshaling Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/ms644501%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from MSDN.

As you can see, some of the functions there have a description, but some has "TBD" in description field. Actually, only those which end with 64 have it. If you take a closer look to one [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/hh309491%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), everything (description, parameters, return value) is TBD as well. Moreover, they don't have "dll" or "library" information associated with them. So what does TBD stand for?

Comment: `TBD` is "to be done". HTH :)

Comment: The doc group doesn't always have luck finding the dev to help them out, it's a big company.  Especially when the technology is ancient, like RPC.  Ten Business Days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`To be done` - in other words, the developer (or documenter in this case) has determined that something needs doing but is far too busy doing cool stuff to worry about such mundane details at this point.

I have code from about twenty years ago that still has `TBD` markers in it :-)

> Aside: I'm actually surprised that MS would allow this to be published as-is - it reeks of unprofessionalism in my opinion. Far better would be to not publish *anything* until you had something useful to say about it.
>
> For a lot of those cases (such as `BSTR_UserFree64` and `BSTR_UserUnmarshal64`), it seems that they're just the same function with `64` tacked on the end, and with exactly the same parameters. They could have just copied the non-64 text across, *especially* when the descriptions hold such vague gems as `"pFlags [in] - The data used by RPC"`. Someone seems to have gone out of their way to *remove* information.

Answer (score 4):

Usually TBD means To Be Determined.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TBD_%28disambiguation%29):

> TBD is an abbreviation often meaning in ordinary writing "to be discussed" "to be done", "to be defined", "to be decided", "to be determined", etc. It may also refer to: ...

According to both [acronymfinder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/TBD.html) and [abbreviations.com](http://www.abbreviations.com/TBD) the abbreviation that ranks the highest is `To Be Determined`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it means To Be Defined...